# I am trying below code but its throwing similar result every time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying below code but its throwing similar result every time.. Let me know if i am doing something wrong

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=in&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=The+Telegraph%27s+Production+Manager+To+Take+Over+The&gws_rd=ssl");
    java.util.List<WebElement> competitor_name = driver.findElements(By.className("slp"));
    for (int i = 0; i < competitor_name.size(); i++) 
    {
    String cmp_name = competitor_name.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_tQb _IId']")).getText();
    System.out.println("Competitor name is : "+cmp_name );
    }
```

Comment: what issue you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below way which will build correct xpath so that we get out of this issue

```
   String cmp_name = competitor_name.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("span[@class='_tQb _IId']")).getText();
```

Comment: in for loop instead